# trying to get the number of months

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

`membership`  table

- membership_startdate (2011-01-12)
- membership_dueday values like only dates (09,08,07)
- member_id

`member` table

- member_id

How can I get count of the number of months that the member has paid till now and taking into consideration (membership_dueday)?  Suppose if `membership_startdate` is 2011-01-01 and `membership_dueday` is 15, the the number of months count up to till now is 5.5

I have tried this code

```
SELECT COUNT(NUMBEROFMONTHS) 
  FROM membership 
 WHERE NUMBEROFMONTHS = PERIOD_DIFF(membership.membership_startdate, CURDATE());
```

It was giving error like this:

> Error Code: 1054
>   Unknown column 'NUMBEROFMONTHS' in 'field list'

...but it does not taking into account the `membership_dueday`...

Answer (score 2):

The 1054 error is because the column does not exist in the table(s) defined in the `FROM` clause.  Additionally, the `WHERE` clause is not used to set a variable, or column alias -- it's for filtering rows returned.

Use [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff):

```
SELECT t.member_id,
       DATEDIFF(LEAST(NOW(), t.membership_dueday), t.membership_startdate) / 30
  FROM MEMBERSHIP t
```

The [LEAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) function will return the lowest of the two dates, so it will use the current date if the due date is in the future.  You can use the `GREATEST` function if you want that reversed.

Comment: "t.membership" this means membership.membership would you pls elaborate this one....

Comment: @user682417: Refresh the page -- I corrected my typo.  The `t` is a table alias, so I don't have to write the entire table name every time.

Comment: it returns the values  DATEDIFF  VALUES like 0.22 , 0.33,2.33 can i get in number of days.....not in points...

Comment: @user682417: Well, you originally posted that you wanted "5.5 months"...  `DATEDIFF` alone will return the number of days -- so if you drop the "/30" I believe that's what you're asking for