# Finding difference between dates

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, datetime, mysql-workbench

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [trying to get the number of months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599140/trying-to-get-the-number-of-months)

I have a

```
                            memberpayments table 
                                totalamountpaid
                                exppayments
                                expmonthly payments
                                dueday
                                memberid
```

I want to find the datediff like this way here I have found the date diff using c#

but I want to find the date diff using mysql

```
  double equivalentPayments = totalamountpaid /expmonthly payments;
  double monthdiff = Math.Ceiling(exppayments - equivalentPayments); 
  monthdiff -= 1;

  int dueDay = 01;

  DateTime expDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths((int)monthdiff).AddDays(DateTime.Today.Day - dueDay);

  int diff = DateTime.Today.Subtract(expDate).Days;
```

I have tried using  Date diff but it was giving the difference between two dates and it was not giving datediff like above solution(c#).

can i get these statements all in one query......using mysql....

would any one pls help me out

Comment: @OMG no its a different question...

Comment: @user832283 it might help if you included some sample data, what you tried and the sample output (incorrect and correct is best), rather than just asking for a port of some c# code

Comment: What are you trying to get that `DATEDIFF` doesn't give you?

Comment: @Micheal I have done in c# i want to find the  date diff     using mysql all in one query  .. thats what i am trying to tell to u .....

Comment: @Michael would you pls give any help .....

Comment: I'm happy to help. It's just not clear what you need that `DATEDIFF` is not giving you. Can you show the query you have tried?

Comment: @Michael    how we convert this one into mysql....     DateTime expDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths((int)monthdiff).AddDays(DateTime.Today.Day - dueDay);

Comment: You can subtract dates just by writing `date1-date2`. You can add months or days via `date1+INTERVAL X DAY/MONTH`.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL have a large set of date time functions. Finding differences between dates are fairly trivial using them :)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

If i understand correctly, all you are after is the difference in days between two dates. This can be done with DATEDIFF(a,b) :)

Comment: ya i have tried datediff... but it was giving date diff between the two dates but it was not giving like the above solution

Comment: how many different ways can you give the difference in days between two dates? :S How does "int diff = DateTime.Today.Subtract(expDate).Days; work? and how does it differ from DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), expDate)?

Comment: I know the datediff is between two dates by using DateDIff(a,b)...     I want the date difference like  in this way....           DateTime expDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths((int)monthdiff).AddDays(DateTime.Today.Day - dueDay);  int diff = DateTime.Today.Subtract(expDate).Days

Comment: you are right ... but i want the above statements all in one query that is using mysql.... is it possible..

Comment: aaah, got ya :) I dont see why not? :) You have all the functions you need in mysql. CEIL(), DATE_ADD, DATE_SUB (or just yourDate + INTERVAL x DAY) and  MAKE_DATE()

Comment: how we convert this statement into mysql                    expDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths((int)monthdiff).AddDays(DateTime.Today.Day - dueDay);

Comment: would you pls help me out....